# Terminology: "L1 regularization" even if I'm using mean instead of sum?

Tags: terminology, regularization, loss-functions

In my loss function I'm using the mean of the log-cosh error between the predictions and targets, as well as an additional regularization term that scales as the *mean* of the absolute value of another quantity in my calculation.

My understanding is that L1 strictly refers to using the sum of absolute values, not their mean, so saying I'm doing "L1 regularization" could be misleading.

**My question is, what terminology should I use to refer to such a regularization term?**  "L1 divided by the number of elements" seems long & pedantic.

PS- The quantities in the error and the quantity in the regularization do not have the same number of elements, so I'd feel odd saying "I calculate the (regularized) loss and divide by the number of elements."

The reason I'm using the mean instead of the sum is so that I don't have to re-engineer the regularization coefficient every time I change the problem size.

**EDIT:** In response to comment, here's the question in mathematical form:

If, strictly speaking, an "L1 regularization" term is applied via something like

$${\rm Loss} = {\rm (other\ \,terms)} + \lambda  \sum_{i=1}^N |y_i| $$,

and instead I'm doing

$${\rm Loss} =  {\rm (other\ \,terms)} + \lambda {1\over N} \sum_{i=1}^N |y_i| $$,

what is the appropriate terminology to refer to this?

I supposed one might say "It's still L1, it's just that you're using a different value for your coefficient."

Comment: Could you write what you are doing out in mathjax?  It would make it a little clearer...

Comment: @jbowman Sure. Added at the bottom.

Comment: You're merely changing the variable from $\lambda$ to $\lambda/N.$  In light of that, both problems are equivalent and both deserve to be characterized as $L^1$ regularization.

Comment: @whuber Thanks! I must've been thinking that and adding it to the edit while you were commenting!  If you want to submit that as an answer -- looks like you're not in need of rep points, LOL, -- I'd be happy to choose your answer.

Comment: Thank you.  I think that in spirit this is the same question as the duplicate--it's certainly answered in the duplicate thread.